# Has Many Limitation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I would like to set a limit to a has_many association. For example, a car has 4 tires. Therefore the Car table should have 4 foreign keys to records in the Tire table.. (note that in this case, each tire can have different priorities and it is for this reason that I need 4 keys)

Anyway I can specify a the number of tire keys in a car record when declaring an association please?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `has_many` association has such an option but you can have a `before_create` validation in your tires model. Assuming that you create tires independently and not via cars using nested forms, below is an example code for your `RAILS_APP/app/models/tire.rb`.

```
Class Tire < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :car
  before_create :four_tires_per_car

  private
  def four_tires_per_car
    # can't create more tires if the car in question already has four tires
    errors[:base] << "A car can have a maximum of four tires" if car.tires.count == 4
  end
end
```

If you are creating tires via car using nested forms, you can modify this example code accordingly.

Comment: @VictorMoroz I am not really sure about this code's behavior during concurrent updates.

Answer (score 0):

No afaik, but you can use the cancan gem to achieve that. For example inside the ability.rb

```
can :create, Car do |car|
   car.tires.count <= 4
end
```